# Appending an ADO.Net Datasource in winforms

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0

I am working with two seperate SQL statements when user conducts a search on my winforms app.
A user can search based on an OrderNumber, OrderDate, ClaimNumber, ClaimDate, CustomerID, CustomerPhone

One SQL statement returns the OrderNumber (in case the user searched based on OrderDate), which is used to execute another SQL statement, which returns the details about the order.

The results are populated in a gridview.

Once the first statement is executed, I have a DataSource (DataSet). How can I append that datasource to display the fields from the second statement as well, keeping in mind, that the first statement could return multiple records, all of which will need to have the appropriate order details correctly linked.

Any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: What are you using as the datasource? DataSet? Entity-Framework? Custom object? SqlResultSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLDataSet? Is this a custom structure? It's not a .net structure is it?

If you are referring to .net DataSet you can use the Merge method to merge 2 datasets.

Comment: .net DataSet. My bad in saying SQL DataSet.

Comment: So yeah you should be able to merge dataset together. This will append your results together.